# What is the best way to upgrade Laravel live project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just joined company where has a big project on the live server which needs to implement new functionality. But the problem that it's running on PHP 5 and Laravel 5. I think before expanding functionality I have to update it to the newest version of Laravel and finally update it to PHP 7. What is the best way to do it? Try to set it up locally and go from there? Or better to use docker? Maybe anybody has some tips on what I should have in mind while updating Laravel versions? As I know everything is in the documentation and you have to update it one by one. For example from Laravel 5 to Laravel 5.1 and so on.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Always set up program locally and test things out as you go. Make sure your local environment is as close to the production environment as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on code structure and how deep is connected with Laravel. There is some helper functions for example which are deprecated. Some functionality is moved to separate packages

Step 1: Write tests for current version. Try to test as much is possible from current code

Step 2: Make a new installation of Laravel

Step 3: Move your controllers, models, migrations and tests to new installation

Step 4: rename helper functions... for example: array_get() to Arr::get()

Step 5: Start running tests and debug. Still Laravel upgrade guide may help here.

Comment: Also always check docs for migration guide, e.g https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#high-impact-changes

Comment: Thank you! I think it's the best way to do that, I will get to work! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Laravel upgrade guide step-by-step:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade

For each version from 5.0 to 5.8, there's a guide to upgrade version by version. You have to do them one-by-one, like 5.0 to 5.1, then 5.1 to 5.2, etc etc. Once you get to 5.8, it goes 5.8 > 6.x, then 6.x to 7.x

It'll be a big endeavour to upgrade from 5.0 to 7.x (current), but it's doable. Alternatively, there's paid services, like Laravel Shift (https://laravelshift.com/) that will do it for you.

Comment: I am struggling to run it locally as it needs php 5, should I do it on docker where I can set up VM for that project?

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. Are you unable to install PHP 5.6 locally? You should be able to have multiple version of PHP installed, but it can be tricky. And docker can handle that, but that's beyond my knowledge scope on how you'd set that up/modify after each upgrade.

Comment: You can use Docker, or Vagrant. Laravel has it's own [Homestead, a pre-packaged Vagrant instance](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead) that you can easily set up, and have multiple sites with different PHP versions.

Comment: Happy to help! Best of luck with the upgrade :)